# How to change the device orientation in android?

Tags: android, orientation, device

I am using a android phone for my development of a kiosk system. The handy uses as standard the portrait mode and will switch with the sensors to landscape if I rotate it to my needs. My problem is that this device programmed layout will do many side by side effekts in runtime because it will always switch to portrait and then remembers the sensor orientation and switches back to landscape. This means the implementation of portrait mode is not very comfortable for my development.
Now I saw in the dev tools the configuration app which shows me a device config:

```
orientation=1
```

My question is: Which file I have to edit to change the device orientation to standard landscape so that the above app will show me landscape. (phone is rooted)

I want to change global from phone portrait mode to tablet landscape mode and not only a single application!

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is edit your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and specify the orientation for your activity, as well as handle orientation changes yourself:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          ...
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          ...
          android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Then your activity will always run in a landscape mode regardless of the device orientation.

**EDIT:** If you want programmatically to enable/disable auto-rotation, then you can use this code:

```
public static void setAutoOrientationEnabled(ContentResolver resolver, boolean enabled)
{
    Settings.System.putInt(resolver, Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enabled ? 1 : 0);
}
```

However note that this will affect all applications running on the device.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My side by side effect comes if I leave my application and therefore leaving the manifest. So I am searching for a system file where I can change the installed android to tablet mode and landscape. The application itself is working with your answer but does not solve the hardware problem. I have another tablet with same android version and this is alwys in landscape mode, however I do not know where to change this :(

Comment: if i understand this, you want so set the mode in your code for each table, once is landscape and the other portrait, right?

Comment: No, I want to keep my phone hardware as a sample demonstrator instead of using a tablet with build in landscape mode. I want to change the system config of android to tablet landscape mode like I would change the global DPI in the build.prob file.

Comment: @JohntheSmith I think I now understand what you're trying to achieve.  I updated my answer with a bit more code.

Comment: I tried to disable the auto orientation but this does not work with the home screen in android 2.2 Froyo and not on the lock screen at all. If you leave a application it goes portrait and then switches to the fixed accelerometer orientation. Because all is recalculated this is a stop for about 5 seconds until you get it back in landscape.

Comment: Found following build.prop entries: ro.sf.hwrotation=90, 180 or 270
ro.build.APP_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE=1
ro.build.APP_ORIENTATION_LANADSCAPE=1 but they have all problems.

Comment: You're correct.  This will not work on the lock screen (and never will, unless you have a custom ROM that supports it), because lock screen does not support orientation in the first place.  As for the home screen, it depends on the launcher you're using.  For example, on my LG phone, it doesn't work on the default LG launcher, but it does work on the Launcher Pro home screen.

Comment: Why custom rom?
All files are editable in android and can be changed right now

Comment: Found out getResources().getConfiguration().orientation will read the platform files. Now I must find out in my platform which files are affected. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html How to change this resources?

Comment: ro.sf.hwrotation=90 or xx in /system/build.prop did the job. Now bootanimation, lockscreen and Android is in landscape.

Answer (score 2):

Hi is this what you are looking for? this would leave the application orientation as landscape.

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

Comment: No, now look at my question:
orientation=1 on portrait mode in devtools
orientation=2 for landscape devices this means somewhere you have to change this value for the device like the DPI settings in the /system/build.prop file. Your code does runtime changes like the sensor would do. I want system setups. The same app which shows me orientation shows me the DPI setting but I do not know the files which are involved.

Comment: This is what I was looking for when Google brought me to this page... so +1.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is 5 yrs old - am answering to help someone reached here later..
I guess every ans here talks about application specific orientation change. Here's what you should consider for changing orientation for the full device

Runtime: In /system/build.prop add:-

```
# Makes portrait only
persist.panel.orientation=90
```

To add in Build tree: Add same in

```
device/<vendor>/<processor>/system.prop
```

Comment: Just to add on this for changing device orientation,you need to delete  /out/target/product/<processor>/recovery/root/default.prop; /out/target/product/<processor>/system/build.prop; /out/target/product/<processor>/system/build.prop.bakforspec; finally make systemImage  to build the image.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the orientation as landscape, add this in your Manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to change it global and not in a single app.